# Sub-MenuItem Selection in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, menu-items

I have the following XAML used to populate a sub-MenuItem listing with RecentDocuments:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Recent Studies" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles}"
          AlternationCount="{Binding Path=Items.Count, 
                                     Mode=OneWay, 
                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource RecentMenuItem}"/>
```

Where in the ViewModel I have the following `RecentFiles` property

```
private ObservableCollection<RecentFile> recentFiles = new ObservableCollection<RecentFile>();
public ObservableCollection<RecentFile> RecentFiles
{
    get { return this.recentFiles; }
    set
    {
        if (this.recentFiles == value)
            return;
        this.recentFiles = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("RecentFiles");
    }
}
```

Now this works fine and displays my recent menu items like so:

[image: MenuItems]

My question is; **how can I bind to the click event on my recent files `MenuItem`s?** I am amble to use `AttachedCommands` but I don't see how this can be achieved.

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MVVM pattern, you do not need Click event at all.

You should use [MenuItem.Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.command.aspx) property in order to communicate with your ViewModel.

**HOW?**

As I can see, you are using the ItemContainerStyle. You can add the following line to that style:

```
<Style x:Key="RecentMenuItem" TargetType="MenuItem">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=SelectCommand}" />
    ...
</Style>
```

And in your `RecentFile`:

```
 public ICommand SelectCommand { get; private set; }
```

You can initialize the command inside the constructor of `RecentFile` class.

Comment: Yes, but how? That _is_ the question. The reason I am having trouble is that the items are populated at run-time...

Comment: Ah of course. Stupidness. However, to get the binding to work from the style you will need: `<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}, Path=DataContext.LoadRecentResourceSet}" />`. Thanks for your time.